# How to create a custom network in hyperledger fabric with ansible?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I'm trying to create a demo network with 2 organization with 1 peer in each using vs code and ibm blockchain platform,I tried creating json files but things got complicated with the wallet.so with the new fabric update things should be easier with ansible but don't know where or how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to understand how to setup a network using the Ansible role for IBM Blockchain Platform. More information can be found here 
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ansible-role-blockchain-platform-manager

and examples can be found here
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ansible-examples

Once you have created your network you can then import the gateways and wallets generated by the ansible role into the IBM Blockchain Extension by adding a new environment according to the information in the github issue here
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues/1848